What causes a rough finish when spraying polyurethane with an hvlp gun?
I started off applying lacquer and poly using a Spraystation; a fan driven sprayer.  For the price it worked very well.  But I'm starting to spray more projects now, and wanted to see if I could avoid the orange peel (as it's time consuming to sand down), so I purchased a 21 Gallon 175 PSI compressor and a 20 oz HVLP gravity spray gun.
I'm using Target Coatings EM9300; a water-based acrylic polyurethane.  Applying to basswood plywood laser-cut pieces.  Following the manufacturer instructions I set the regulator to 30 psi and sprayed a layer every 70 minutes or so.
My first job went okay, but I ended up with a rather 'rough' finish, almost like sandpaper in texture.  I waited a day, sanded using 240 grit, and sprayed a final coat.  I ended up without the roughness, but a more intense orange peel than I did with the Spraystation.
Reading that others had trouble with the built-in regulator, I purchased an inline one and tried again.  Similar results.  Some forums suggested higher air pressure, but when I turned it up to 50 it started blowing my pieces around so I gave up on that.  Next I tried reducing with water (about 30% water to 70% poly), but same results again.
I have seen many Youtube videos of people spraying and coming up with a mirror finish without any sanding or buffing necessary.  Granted, they are usually inside and I'm spraying outside, but I'm hoping outdoor contaminants can't be causing all these issues.  I considered sanding between coats, but the internet says to wait 6 hours to sand and pulling my equipment out for 4 days in a row is unfortunately impractical.
Is it possible to spray a relatively smooth finish in one day, or am I stuck without a clean spray booth and several days of time?

I usually would try to spray with a lower pressure. Another variable to experiment with would be viscosity. Years ago I switched to HVLP.

"Is it possible to spray a relatively smooth finish in one day" OK well this is the heat of the Q and the answer is definitely yes, as obviously people can do so. You've clearly done research, I'm surprised the cause (and I believe it to be the cause, unless the finish is faulty) of a sandpapery surface is finish drying on the way to the project, which boils down to spraying from too far away, although there are other factors including temp, RH, direct sunlight. Before I say the next bit, "My first job went okay" is worrisome, as it sounds like you didn't do any testing.... vital!

So overall, it sounds like you have enough spraying under your belt that you'll appreciate (perhaps unconsciously?) that there's a sort of Venn diagram of finish type, viscosity, pressure, distance and tip movement. They all work together and there's a sweet spot, or perhaps several, in there somewhere.... which is what testing ideally will reveal. But that aside, sometimes the gear lets you down. I assume it's safe to discount the air itself (since it doesn't sound like there're any of the characteristic issues) so how about the specific gun? Does it spray something else well? Spanking clean?

Aaand sometimes the finish itself is what's letting you down. During your hunting around did you come across this, Micro bubble hell on Woodweb?
